# Are ARN names of Lambda static or do they change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, lambda

Do the ARN name of a Lambda changes? I would like to know whether they are static or dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are static - in case it not obvious, the ARN is built from: a static prefix + the region it is in + your account number + your function name.

So the ARN will always be the same as long it you don't rename the function, don't move it to another region and you keep it in the same account.